# How to have active link when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty stumped on this project where I have a one page site. I want to be able to scroll down or up the page and have my navigation change it's active links.

Here is my test site.

http://ebresearch1.wpengine.com

I've tried a scroll script, but my site has some off canvas css and js that kills the scroll script.

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on getting this to work. I can provide any code or more information if needed.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not test for `location.hash`? For example, change your fifth circle's classname from `"inactive-circle"` to `"active-circle"` if the hash is `"#fifthSection"`.

Comment: Will it test as the user scrolls or only on load? I saw an example somewhere that had test if div was in view, but it didn't work as user scrolled. Do you have an example? Sorry, not that great at code from scratch.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, please see the answer I just added.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the offset on each of your sections, and set the nav circle corresponding to the closest section to the top.

I see you're on `jquery`, in `jquery` you can just use the `.offset()` property of each section div. For example if you want to check if a certain element `section1` is close to the top, you can do something like:

```
var section = $('#section1')
if (section.offset() < 20) { // experiment and find your own value for this
    set_active_circle(1);
}
```

You should better split this into a function that finds which section is closest to the top, then call another function (such as `set_active_circle`) to activate the corresponding circle and deactivate the rest.

Comment: Can you help me with this, I'm not certain how to implement this on my current page. If you need me to send you code, let me know. I appreciate your help.